# como crear un script en php que haga un screenshot y modifique el nombre cada que tome la captura

Tags: php, script

buenas mi duda es la siguiente como puedo hacer para realizar un script en php que al momento de tomar la captura de pantalla me modifique el nombre y no me cambie la imagen ya guardada.. mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<?php

function reporte($i){
    require ('config.php');
    $i++;
    $Nombre = "Reporte".$i;
    $guardado = "../img/".$Nombre.".jpeg";
    $img = imagegrabscreen();
    $destino_1 = imagejpeg($img,$guardado);


            $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Fallo al conectar con la Base de Datos.";

                exit();

            }

            mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_bd) or die ("No se encontro la Base de Datos");

            mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
    $guardar= "INSERT INTO img (ID, Nombre, Lugar) VALUES (0, '$Nombre', '$guardado') ";

        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$guardar);

        mysqli_close($conexion);
    sleep(30)
    return $Nombre(); 
}
while (true) {
    $i(2);
}
?>
```

pues la verdad no soy muy bueno en php pero lo poco que se y eh investigado es lo que hago, y ya eh buscado en varias paginas pero no consigo nada. que quiero hacer con mi script pues que tome una capture de pantalla cada 15min y me guarde la foto en la base de datos, en este caso solo eh guardado la ruta para no ocupar mucho espacio en la base de datos, pero me sale error al momento de usar el sleep() y cuando guardo la foto me reemplaza la anterior que ya habia tomado. de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: el id es el mismo siempre `0`

Comment: @aloMalbarez gracias por tu comentario, pero la verdad no entendi eso que dijiste que el id siempre es 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios errores de logica.  Primero, la variable `$i` deberia de ser una variable global.  Luego en el `while` llamarias a tu funcion con esa variable global.  Finalmente, necesitas diferenciar entre la variable global y el parametro de la funcion.  Puedes cambiarle el nombre a `$j` y siempre amumentas la variable global dentro de la funcion.  Algo asi:

```
<?php
$i = 2;
function reporte($j){
    require ('config.php');
    $i++;
    $Nombre = "Reporte".$j;
    $guardado = "../img/".$Nombre.".jpeg";
    $img = imagegrabscreen();
    $destino_1 = imagejpeg($img,$guardado);    

            $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Fallo al conectar con la Base de Datos.";

                exit();

            }

            mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_bd) or die ("No se encontro la Base de Datos");

            mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
    $guardar= "INSERT INTO img (ID, Nombre, Lugar) VALUES (0, '$Nombre', '$guardado') ";

        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$guardar);

        mysqli_close($conexion);
    sleep(30);
    return $Nombre; 
}
while (true) {
    reporte($i);
}
?>
```

Otra cosa, este script nunca terminaria de correr.  Quizas sea mejor que hagas un `cron` en lugar del `while`.

Comment: muchas gracias por responder ya resolvi mi duda :D tambien estaba buscando lo de cron y mientras eso termine pensando en algo :D!!! a qui les dejo mi codigo de que fue lo que hice :D!!!

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias por responder ya resolvi mi duda :D tambien estaba buscando lo de cron y mientras eso termine pensando en algo :D!!! a qui les dejo mi codigo de que fue lo que hice :D!!!

```
<?php
$i=0;
while ($i<=3) {
    require ('config.php');
    $i++;
    $Nombre = "Reporte".$i;
    $guardado = "../img/".$Nombre.".jpeg";
    $img = imagegrabscreen();
    $destino_1 = imagejpeg($img,$guardado);    

            $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Fallo al conectar con la Base de Datos.";

                exit();

            }

            mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_bd) or die ("No se encontro la Base de Datos");

            mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
    $guardar= "INSERT INTO img (ID, Nombre, Lugar) VALUES (0, '$Nombre', '$guardado') ";

        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$guardar);

        mysqli_close($conexion);
    sleep(5);
}
?>
```